# How I clear a transaction from ecommerce data in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a problem with my ecommerce data in google analytics. I made a wrong transaction and sent it to GA. So how I can remove this transaction? Thanks

http://www.ga-script.org/en/posts/2012/05/remove-e-commerce-transactions-from-google-analytics
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1037443?hl=en
I read two above article, but I don't really understand how it work!
Anyone can help me? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot remove or reverse transactions from Google Analytics, headlines in Google support pages notwithstanding (actually they point out that "reversing a transaction does not remove it").

What you can do is offset a transaction value by sending a transaction with the a corresponding negative amount in the transaction, and negative quantities for the products in the transaction. Under the right circumstances this will look as if the transactions where actually reversed.

However internally this will be recorded as two transactions, with a number of consequences:

- both transactions will recorded for different times. So if you choose a timeframe that includes the original transaction, but not the "negative" transaction you will still see the wrong amount (they cancel each other out only as long as they both in the viewed timeframe)
- You need to take care to attribute both transactions to the same traffic/marketing channel, else they will mess up channel-based revenue reporting (since the original transaction will be attributed to one channel, the negative transaction to another)
- double transactions will affect your conversion rates, so if you are doing this often your conversion rate will look a lot better than it actually is

In my opinion this creates more problems than it solves.

However if you still want to do this I am not sure how one can be clearer than the linked Google support article (the other link refers to a deprecated version of GA). Send a transaction with the same id as the transaction you want to cancel out, set the transaction revenue to the negative amount, and when you sent the products use negative quantities.

In Universal Analytics you can measure refunds if you use Enhanced E-Commerce-Tracking. This will not reverse the transaction, but will allow you to calculate an adjusted revenue that does not contain refunded transactions.

Comment: Thanks @eike-pierstorff . Your answer is very detail. I made a reserve transaction. Like what you wrote, the transaction didn't remove. But after the time I made reserve transaction, I didn't see id of that transaction on my report. That what I want. Again, thank you so much!